# problem with "multiple definition" 

Tags: c, header, multiple-definition-error

Say I have a very little header file like so:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

void print();
int getInt()
{ //ERROR HERE
    return 5;
}

#endif /* A_H_ */
```

And a source file implementing print like so:

```
#include "a.h"

void print()
{
    printf("%d\n",getInt()); //WARNING HERE
}
```

And my main() function code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

int main(void)
{
    print();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Notice that `getInt` is defined in the header file and invoked in the source file.
When I compile I get `multiple definition of`getInt'` in the header file, but I've only
defined it once! The source file (.c) only invokes it. What is my problem? 
Thanks

Comment: As given, this would compile just fine. Your real problem probably includes the header twice, or includes it in multiple files.

Comment: Rule number one for posting code in a question: make sure it *actually reproduces the problem*.  You would have found the solution by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably including your header file into another source file too. You may try to move the definition to the .c file or declare `getInt()` as `inline`.

Comment: True, I include it in both a.c and main.c, but I still don't understand the problem.... Notice I've added the code in main.c

Comment: The problem is that C preprocessor is dumb. And `#include` does exactly what its name implies: It includes the contents of a file in to another one. So, when you try to compile your program, the linker sees that `getInt` is defined in both `main.c` and `a.c`, hence the error. Declaring it as `inline` solves the problem because inline functions act as if they don't have a definition, they only have a declaration. Multiple declarations are ok, but the definition must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `getInt()` into a.c, i.e.

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

void print(void);
int getInt(void);

#endif /* A_H_ */
```

a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

void print(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",getInt());
}

int getInt(void)
{
    return 5;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

int main(void)
{
    print();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As a rule of thumb, *interfaces* (i.e. *prototypes* for externally accessible function, plus related typedefs and constants etc) belong in .h files, while *omplementations* (i.e. actual function definitions, plus private (static) functions and other internal stuff) belong in .c files.